# Chrome Extension Script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I've created a chrome extension which will find a USPS tracking number on text highlight. My current code is working great but I wanted to make some modification.

Here's the manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "background" : { "scripts": ["background.js"] },
  "description": "Track on USPS",
  "icons": {
  "default_icon": "usps.png"
      },
  "minimum_chrome_version": "29.0", 
  "name": "USPS",
  "permissions": [ "contextMenus", "tabs", "http://*/*",
  "https://*/*" ],
  "version": "1.0"
}
```

This is the background.js:

```
/**
* Returns a handler which will open a new tab when activated.
*/
function searchgoogle(info)
{
  var searchstring = info.selectionText;
  chrome.tabs.create({url: "https://tools.usps.com/go/TrackConfirmAction?qtc_tLabels1=" + searchstring})
}

chrome.contextMenus.create({title: "Search USPS", contexts:["selection"], onclick: searchgoogle});

/**
* Create a context menu which will only show up for images.
*/
chrome.contextMenus.create({
  "title" : "Search tracking number on USPS",
  "type" : "normal",
  "contexts" : ["text"],
  "onclick" : getClickHandler()
});
```

Now I wanted to modify the current script:

```
https://tools.usps.com/go/TrackConfirmAction?qtc_tLabels1=" + searchstring
```

with the script below. This new code will open a pop up window. I tried modifying the new script but to no avail. Can anyone help me out?

Here's the new script that I wanted to use:

```
javascript:new function(){window.open('https://tools.usps.com/go/TrackConfirmAction?qtc_tLabels1=' + window.getSelection().toString(), '_blank', 'toolbar=0,location=0,menubar=0,top=91,height=900,width=650,left=1475');};
```

Thanks a lot in advance! This community help me a lot with my projects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't look like you're actually calling the function you're creating in the script (and you can't because it isn't named).  Try removing the function, and just executing the code:

```
javascript:window.open('https://tools.usps.com/go/TrackConfirmAction?qtc_tLabels1=' + window.getSelection().toString(), '_blank', 'toolbar=0,location=0,menubar=0,top=91,height=900,width=650,left=1475');
```

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured it out!

```
function searchgoogle(info) {
var searchstring = info.selectionText;
chrome.windows.create({url: "https://tools.usps.com/go/TrackConfirmAction?qtc_tLabels1=" + searchstring})
}


chrome.contextMenus.create({
"title": "Search USPS",
"contexts":["selection"],
"onclick": searchgoogle
});
```